# How to find open Xamarin Android or iOS csproj file in Visual Studio Solution Explorer

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

How does one open the .csproj file of an Android or iOS project within visual studio, other than opening the file manually from file explorer? Clicking on a project always jumps to the properties file GUI editor that opens by default when you click on the project or right-click and select Properties. The associated .csproj file isn't visible in the solution explorer.

Thanks

[What I see when clicking on a Xamarin Android Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY8Q7.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a `Xamarin.Forms` project,you just need doule click in the Solution Explorer, not Android or iOS projects.

If it is `Xamarin.Android` or `Xamarin.ios` project,you need right click your project,then `Unload Project`,then right click your project again,click `Edit Project File`.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to then to find this question which answered my next question as to why the UX is that way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134170/whats-the-point-of-unloading-project-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

in Solution Explorer, right click and select "Edit Project File"

Comment: hmmm... I don't see that option after right clicking on the project in my VS 2019 16.8.1.