# How to set 'EmbedAssembliesIntoApk' MSBuild property to 'true' in Visual Studio for Mac on Android project?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a issue in my android project, and want to set EmbedAssembliesIntoApk to true ?

The error is:

```
error XA0130: Please disable fast deployment in the Visual Studio project property pages or edit the project file in a text editor and set the 'EmbedAssembliesIntoApk' MSBuild property to 'true'.
```

From where can I set EmbedAssembliesIntoApk to true ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Maui project click right then select properties in last

expand Android then select options
go to Fast deployment then uncheck all

[image]

Answer (score 8):

From your error message, you can take a look about [Fast Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/building-apps/build-process#fast-deployment), Fast deployment works by further shrinking Android application package size.

To remove this error message,there are two ways to do, one is to double-click **Android project Properties**---select **Android Options**---disable **Use Fast Development(Debug mode only)**

Fast deployment is enabled by default, and may be disabled in Debug builds by setting the `$(EmbedAssembliesIntoApk)` property to True.

Another way is to go to the **csproj file**,  try placing `<EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>` within the Debug configuration `PropertyGroup`

About go to the **csproj file**, you can take a look:

[How to find open Xamarin Android or iOS csproj file in Visual Studio Solution Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64902165/how-to-find-open-xamarin-android-or-ios-csproj-file-in-visual-studio-solution-ex)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem deploying to the device from Visual Studio for Mac.
During the deployment, it just shows the "Fast deploying" message and never ends.
In the project options, Fast deployment was disabled, but I added the

`<EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>` directly in the csproj and it solved it. Now it really deploys fast.

[image]